# Do we need to change the header?

Tags: android

If i am using this code for a  particular url then its working but if i change the url of exactly same type then is it necessary to change the `getRequest.setHeader("User-Agent",  "xxxx") (other than xxxx)` or it will not cause any problem ?

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String getUrl = "http://myurl.com";

HttpUriRequest getRequest = new HttpGet(getUrl);

getRequest.setHeader("User-Agent",  "xxxx");

 HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
 int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

 log.info("statusCode=" + statusCode);

Document doc = null;
        if (statusCode == 200 ){
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            //String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                doc = builder.parse(entity.getContent());
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                           
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `User-Agent` header identifies your methods to the server. It's like saying *hey, by the way, I'm using this program to send you this request!*. Firefox, Chrome and Safari each have their own recognizable `User-Agents`, for example.

It rarely has anything to do with the rest of the conversation you're having. You need not change it, nor probably set it in the first place, unless you have very specific reasons to.

Happy coding!